# Update javascript variable on server, from script running on client

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

Hi I have a webpage that includes some javascript to locate my machine, I want to be able to update the variables that are included in the javascript from a script that runs on my machine, Im just wondering to know is this at all possible
Below is the code

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: coords,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
            );
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map: map,
                title: "Your current location!"
        });

    });
}else {
    alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
}
```

The variables I want to be able to update are the position.coords.latitude
and the position.coords.longitude
but done from my laptop
Thanks for any input?

Comment: Thanks not familiar with Jquery but ill have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

Make geolocation request every x seconds:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
        );
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coords,
            map: map,
            title: "Your current location!"
    });

 $.ajax({
     url: 'ajax-file', //create a file that querys your lap top position
     success: function (response){
         map.setCenter(response);
     } 
 });
```

The ajax file may be a php file or aspx file you just need to query
     SELECT lat, long FROM table 
and echo it to the file then you catch that value with ajax

Comment: Thanks but how does this change my variables to being updated from a script on my laptop?

Comment: Ok you see the reason why im trying to change the variables value is because when this code is run its only showing where the server is on a map, now if I can update the variables from my laptop with my laptops co-ordinates then I would be able to track where my laptop is, which is what I want to do, im not sure this would work for that problem, but correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition finds where your lap top is in the map is this what are you looking for?

Comment: No you see thats just finding where the server is, what I want to do is find where my laptop is, so that from any device I go to my website and it shows me where my laptop is everytime. So to do this I thought having some kind of script running on my laptop that updates the variables so that now rather than tracking the server its tracking the laptop

Comment: Now i understand you need to store the location of your lap top to a database then access the database by mobile or another source then you find your lap top location

Comment: Cool thanks so if I read it right, I update my code with this, and then have an ajax file on my laptop that contains my long an lat co-ordinates, so that now its tracking my laptop instead of the server? if I have read it wrong I apologise Jquery and ajax is something ive never done

Comment: Its a lot more complex than that check this https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 how to integrate php/ajax/mysql you need a lot of work man :)

Comment: Great well thanks a million for all your help, I appreciate it

Comment: @JackW - `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` gives the current position of the computer that is executing the script -- javascript is client-side. If you use PHP/AJAX to get geolocation data created in PHP, **then** you will get the geolocation of the server, as PHP is server-side.

Comment: @Chris He wants to track his lap top php/ajax is the only way to track it so yes server-side is the only way

Comment: If he wants to put or retrieve the location data in a database, then yes AJAX is one way to get the data to the server. As far as gathering the geolocation data about the client, that is javascript. I am reply to his comment above, that `getCurrentPosition ` is "just finding where the server is" -- there seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding here on the part of the OP about aspects of the technology.

Comment: Ok maybe just to reiterate my question, the code I have in my OP works what would seem perfectly on my webpage, the problem is that this is not tracking my laptops co-ordinates rather the server from where the code is placed and running from. What I want to do is to change the variables so that I can have a script running on my own machine that pushes the co-ordinates of the machine into those two variables. So that now when I go to my webpage it doesnt show the location of my server but rather my laptop